# Cannot find installable ISAM Visual Studio 2012

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

I'm having some difficulty with an application I'm working on for school. I'm trying to call a database I made in access to load in id codes to a combobox in Visual Basic. I'm using a 64bit version of windows 8.1 and office 2013. And visual studio ultimate 2012. I have already installed 2010 access database engine. I'll start by showing you my code.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class VDObjects

    Public Shared strConn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Arcanum\Documents\VincentMcMullen\VandelayDB.accdb;Persist Secruity Info=False;"

    Public Class Department

        'Department ID
        Private DeptIDValue As String
        Public Property DeptID() As String
            Get
                Return DeptIDValue
            End Get

            Set(ByVal value As String)
                DeptIDValue = value
            End Set

        End Property

        'Department Description
        Private DeptDescrValue As String
        Public Property DeptDescr() As String
            Get
                Return DeptDescrValue
            End Get

            Set(ByVal value As String)
                DeptDescrValue = value
            End Set

        End Property


        'populate a drop down box with all available users
        Public Shared Sub PopulateDropdown(ByRef cbSelect As ComboBox)
            Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
            con.ConnectionString = strConn

            'SQL Query to get department IDs
            Dim qry As String = "SELECT DepartmentID FROM tblDepartments "
            Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(qry, con)

            Try
                'first clear the current entries
                cbSelect.Items.Clear()

                'run and add query and add the values
                con.Open()
                Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

                While reader.Read()
                    cbSelect.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0))
                End While

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            Finally
                con.Close()
            End Try

        End Sub



    End Class





End Class
```

It will fail on the line that reads "con.Open()" and immediately go to the catch. I will tell me it "cannot find an installable ISAM." I've already reinstalled office, and verified they are both the 64 bit versions per microsoft support suggestions. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thankyou

Vince

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo ("Secruity") in your connection string:

```
Persist Secruity Info=False;
```

... should be ...

```
Persist Security Info=False;
```

... although you really don't need to include that parameter because `False` is the default value.

Comment: Gord Thompson you are amazing. I have been racking my brain on that one and that two letter mishap fixed the issue. I thankyou sir.